# Is slow cooking for 24+ hours safe?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, pork, slow-cooking

I've been cooking a 15 lb (7 Kg) pork shoulder for 24 hours, and the temperature has been around 140°F (60°C) for both meat and liquid. I didn't realize the temp was so low until just now when I stuck a thermometer in it.

Its a new (to me) slow roaster that is quite large, and has temperature written on the dial.  I had the dial set to 275°F (135°C), but obviously the actual temperature is much lower that.

I've turned up the temperature and will get it to a cooking temp of 275°F, but **will it be safe to keep cooking the meat this way?** I think I should get the meat close to 190°F (90°C).